# I want to send a tempertaure sensor data to my computer using a USB port in the cheapest most efficient way

Tags: usb, sensor, raspberry-pi

I have to design a product, which takes a temperature sensor (-50:150 celsius), this data needs to be get digitized and then through the USB port needs to be sent to my Raspberry pi.
         I figure there would be ADC, USB interface involved, since the sensor is 50 feet away from the computer, I would require amplifier.

Can someone help me by suggesting the parts that I should be using.

the only power source for this should be through my Pi's USB port

Comment: 50ft = 15m. USB1 spec= 5m, USB2 spec=5m, USB3=3m.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002VA813U) USB thermometer coupled with something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006JTMFYK) repeater cable should work...

Answer (score 0):

Digispark USB Development Board can be used to do that. It has Attiny85  microcontroller. Can read temperature from a temperature sensor or a thermistor. Kindly check the links below...

http://hackaday.com/2011/09/17/attiny-hacks-simple-usb-temperature-probe/

http://flux242.blogspot.in/2012/06/avr-stick-as-temperature-logger.html

Hope this helps...